# Abaqus Failure for I-Beam Section in Major direction only

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, beam, abaqus, software

For my 4th year dissertation in Civil Engineering I've got to investigate the difference between BS5950, Eurocode 3 and ABAQUS failures. The only thing is, in the BS5950 and Eurocode 3 the failure can only include Major OR Minor axis which is what I need. However, in ABAQUS, the software itself 'decides' in which way it will fail. It starts with Major axis but at the end it takes into account the Minor axis too which gives me an error in comparing these results with the BS and Eurocode.

My question is, is there any way you can tell ABAQUS that the only way the failure can occur is in Major axis? without taking into account the Minor axis.

I'm using BBC Basic to create the ABAQUS input files and then run them through the Command. I have already tried to put 'boundary conditions' (a maximum length it can move along) but it gave me a too high of an error between with and without the boundary conditions so I can't do that.

Has anyone ever do that kind of investigation? Any advice/ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standards use simplified method of defining failures most times based on experimental data. On that other hand, FEA Software try to simulate exactly what happens in your material.

I am not familiar with abacus but I am familiar with FE and other programs. In order to trigger failure, you have to reach the stress of your yield criterion. I am not really sure if you can change your criterion for each direction thought.

An other way is to cheat by assuming an anisotropic material, rasing enough your material's stiffness of one of the axis will eventually trigger failure in the other axis.

If I were you, I would first try to connect the failure in the other axis with a different part of the standard (that failure should be checked somewhere). Then setup the problem in a way that your main axis will be the crucial.